# Jenkins ssh-agent unable to find credentials

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, ssh

I am trying to use ssh-agent to push commits to a remote git repository from a scripted Jenkins pipeline.

I have installed the plugin and have added the SSH private key to the Credentials section on Jenkins. THe following is a snippet from a Groovy class instantiated and called from the Jenkinsfile:

```
stages.sshagent(credentials:['26954b1f-2e32-4b4b-8923-3b7a9fbac6c9']) {
    stages.sh "git push origin ${branchName}"
}
```

Note:stages is just a representation of the stage within the Jenkinsfile. The class compiles fine but show the following error message each time:

```
FATAL: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
```

If I use the credentials with the git client then it works fine but unfortunately this does not support git push.

Answer (score 9):

This question has a few days(944) without answer and I think you may be already solved the problem, but just for the record. I think the problem you have/had its that you haven't indicated the credential ID in your code or the ID 26954b1f-2e32-4b4b-8923-3b7a9fbac6c9 isn't the correct one.

To add a private key to Jenkins, go to:

> Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global credentials
>
> > Select SSH Username with private key then in ID field
>
> Nota: you need to have the installed the [SSH Agent Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)

[image: Jenkins-print-screen-ssh-agent-credential]

**ID:**

> An internal unique ID by which these credentials are identified
>   from jobs and other configuration. Normally left blank, in which case
>   an ID will be generated, which is fine for jobs created using visual
>   forms. Useful to specify explicitly when using credentials from
>   scripted configuration.

Groovy code sample

```
sshagent(['jenkins-ssh-qa']) {
    sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no devops@172.1.1.1 ${dockerRun}"
}
```